# GE GSH25JSRFSS refrigerator water dispenser not working

Tags: water, refrigerator, valve

I have a GE GSH25JSRFSS.  The water dispenser isn't working but ice maker still works.  As the solenoid going to the water dispenser read 0 ohms, I replaced the part, first testing the resistance on the new part which was fine.  Still no water through the dispenser after the replacement.  I took the new solenoid off and tested it again and this time it read 0 ohms.  My best guess is that something is shorting it out.  Any idea what it might be or what my next steps should be?

Comment: Check the input signal to the solenoid.  If it's providing a voltage higher than rated, that could damage the coil and cause a short circuit.

Comment: Thank you jwh20.  The solenoid was rated for 20W. and I tested the amps and volts. 
20W = .174A x 115V.  All was fine.

Answer (score 2):

I replaced the controller board (which was easy to do) and still no water.  I tested the ohms on the old and new solenoid and now they are reading around 307 ohms.  I have no explanation for that.  Very strange.

I started thinking maybe there is a clog in the line.  In the middle of the water dispenser line I was able to find a connector (at the front bottom left of the refrigerator) which allowed me to separate the line which I did.  I pressed the water dispenser handle and water came out at the separation. I put the line back together.

After further research I found out that it was possible for the water to freeze within the line.  I took a weed eater line and pushed it through the line where the water comes out and it stopped at 6 inches.  I turned off the power on the freezer side, removed all the food from the freezer and left it's door open for a couple of hours.  The next time I tested the water dispenser water was coming through.  Issue resolved.

Comment: Excellent detective work! Thanks for coming back to share your answer with the world, I'm sure this will help someone else in the future. Please also come back in about 48 hours to click the check mark next to your answer so others know that this does have a solution.

Comment: So you found ice in the line?  You may have an issue with your defrost and/or blend door from the freezer cabinet causing the temp in the fridge cabinet to drop too low (or maybe you just have the fridge cabinet set too cold).